# web.config transformation + msdeploy - keeping production passwords out of source control

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy, web.config-transform

Our web.config needs a database password.

How can we specify this password while building the msdeploy (aka Web Deploy) package or when actually deploying?

We build the msdeploy package using msbuild (/p:DeployOnBuild=true) and web.config transformations for environment-specific details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web.config transformations are, by design, *build time* transformations. I tend to only use them for "everything but debug" changes.

What you want is an MSDeploy parameter. Assuming you are using a `pubxml` publish profile, the generated package will automatically have a parameter named "*Name*-Web.config Connection String" (where "Name" matches the name attribute in web.config) that will apply to the connection string.

If you deploy the package, you can change the connection string by supplying the value using `-setParam`:

```
Website.deploy.cmd /Y ... ^
 -setParam:name="Name-Web.config Connection String",value="connection_string"
```

If you deploy using a publish profile, you can set the value in the `pubxml` file by updating the `MSDeployParameterValue` value (you should see the correct value near the bottom of the file):

```
<MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)DBName-Web.config Connection String">
  <ParameterValue>connection_string</ParameterValue>
</MSDeployParameterValue>
```

Comment: the ```Name-Web.config``` just apply for connection string? What happen if I wanna to change AppSettings attribute?